# iPhone 7 battery discharges very fast after using Waze and charging 3 hours from the car

Tags: iphone, battery

I charged my iPhone 7 (iOS 11.3.1) from car for about 3-4 hours during the ride and Waze app was on all the time. Next day I noticed that phone discharges really fast. Power saving mode helps, but also the problem still appear. And the problem is not in apps running in background that could take power too much. Now it also gets very hot when charging, like never before. What could be the problem? Could it be that the battery life is almost over?

Comment: What power source or car adapter are you using?  It sounds like it’s less than phone needs.  Screen always on AND full time GPS uses much power.  Needs good power source AND good quality charge cable.

Comment: I used Philips usb adapter with original Apple cable.

Comment: Can you link the Phillips USB adapter?  I just googled and can’t get specific device to read specs... there too many different things that google to “Phillips USB adapter”

Comment: https://images.philips.com/is/image/PhilipsConsumer/DLP2259_10-IMS-en_SG?$jpglarge$&wid=1250

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes trying to find that item with various search methods, even using the search box on Phillips.com... I still can’t locate specifications for the item to see how many watts or amps it produces.

Comment: The moral tho, I had a cheap car adapter for a long time, it caused similar symptoms.  After upgrading to [this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B072DTDB1W?ref=yo_pop_ma_swf) because I wanted to charge an iPad as well, I no longer had iPhone charging issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I can change the adapter to better, but the problem is that my phone battery because of that ride now seems to be damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the USB Car charger doesn't have the [MFi](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action) (made for iPhone) logo then it is probably a cheap charger with minimal over-voltage protection circuits inside, even if it says Philips on the outside. This can cause damage to the charge circuit on your phone's logic board and ultimately your battery.

Waze really sucks the juice out of a battery and having that charger on for 3-4 hours straight may have damaged your phone. Try running your phone inside and charging with an Apple original wall cube to see if that makes a difference. If not, then you will need to have that phone looked at by either Apple or an independent micro-soldering repair shop.